# Converting raw image into mono8

Tags: ros, video

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to use the ethzasl_ptam node. Curently, I am passing an image to it using my webcam with the uvc_camera node. I am getting clean raw footage from the uvc_camer node (I can see in with rqt), but the screan that comes up with the ptam node is weird looking. After looking around online, I think this is happening becouse the ptam node needs mono8 video, not color. I have been looking around for how to change the video type, and the best way seems to be with opencv. However, I haven't fpund any tutorials I understand. I've tried to follow [this](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython) one, but I am not sure I followed it corectlly. My computer didn't think I wrote a node when I tried to implement the file on the tutorial (auto-tab didn't work, and when I used rosrun I got a "cv in neithe a node or a package" error message) and when I ran it with ./cv.py an error poped up

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cv.py", line 3, in <module>
    roslib.load_manifest('my_package')
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 62, in load_manifest
    sys.path = _generate_python_path(package_name, _rospack) + sys.path
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 93, in _generate_python_path
    m = rospack.get_manifest(pkg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 163, in get_manifest
    return self._load_manifest(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 207, in _load_manifest
    retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name, rospack=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 199, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: my_package
```

Any direction anyone can offer would be apriciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211120/converting-raw-image-into-mono8/) by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2015-06-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One possibly easier way to solve your original problem is to use [image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc). If you run `image_proc` correctly it will automatically create a `/my_camera/image_mono` topic that your `ethzasl_ptam` node can subscribe to (probably with some [remapping](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments)).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on 2015-06-15**:
Thanks, I just got it to work using image proc. Now I'm need to put it in a nice little launch file.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've added a nodelet here https://github.com/lucasw/image_manip to convert most types to most other types: rgb, bgr and mono of 8/16/32/64 to any other (but yuv422 isn't supported yet).  Dynamic reconfigure is used to change the destination types.

I haven't tested all the combinations so likely there is some wrong behavior and errors.

[image: image description]

rqt_image_view doesn't support some of the types, though adding mono32 or bgr64 etc. support to it won't be too hard.

[This is an example launch](https://github.com/lucasw/image_manip/blob/master/image_manip/launch/convert.launch) file using a stored image.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-09-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1